# Adding multiple column entries into single row

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a query in vb.net and SQL.

I have 2 tables

**student** with columns like

```
s_id, name, address, gender, contact, class,
```

**subject** with these columns:

```
s_id, subject1
s_id, Subject2
s_id, Subject3
```

Now I want to merge the result as

```
s_id, name, address, gender, contact, class, subject1, subject2, subject3
```

For each individual student.

Kindly help me with the solution.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: which database you are using ?? sql is aquery  language not a db

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: The JOIN you need depends on whether you want to see only matching records, missing records from one of the sides or all missing records.

Comment: Show the sql query you are using that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for. Check if following helps.

```
Select s_id,name,address,gender,contact,class,Subject1,Subject2,Subject3
from
(
    SELECT stu.s_id,stu.name,stu.address,stu.gender,stu.contact,stu.class,sub.subject from Student stu
    join Subject sub on (stu.s_id = sub.s_id)
) p
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(subject)
    FOR subject in ([Subject1],[Subject2],[Subject3])
) as pvt
```

Above query would give you following result. 
s_id    name    address gender  contact class   Subject1    Subject2    Subject3

1   Name1   Address1    F       A   1   1   0

2   Name2   Address2    M       A   0   0   1

3   Name3   Address3    F       B   0   0   0

Check it here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/804a7/1